# VLOOKUP With Another Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I get a "Subscript Out of Range" error. I have two Workbooks. I am trying to VLOOKUP values into each sheet of Workbook A from its corresponding sheet in the Workbook B. The sheet names are the same in both workbooks except that the first workbook has some additional sheets without corresponding sheets in Workbook B. Where am I going wrong.

```
Sub Update1()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
x = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

For y = 1 To x

    Dim wsheet As String '1
    Dim wrange As Range     '2
    wsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(y).Name '3
    Set wrange = Application.Workbooks("2012SWD.xlsx").Worksheets(wsheet).Range("A1:G100") '4
    For n = 1 To 100
        If SOME CONDITION Then
           Sheets(y).Range("T" & n).Value = WorsheetFunction.VLookup("A" & n, wrange, 3, False)
        End If
    Next n

Next y


End Sub
```

The problem is with one of more of the lines 1,2,3,4

SOME CONDITION is `Left(Sheets(y).Range("A" & n), 2) Like "CA"`

Comment: Either: `ActiveWorkbook` has <y sheets, there is no open workbook named "2012SWD.xlsx", or there is, but it doesn't have a sheet named `wsheet`.

Comment: ActiveWorkbook has y sheets, cos I have set the no of sheets in the Active workbook to X and y takes values from 1 to X . 2012SWD.xlsx was open. First two of your possibilities are totally ruled out, the third possibility highlighted by you is the cause of the error message. I am setting a range variable with a range on a Sheet that does not exist.

Comment: I solved the problem by running the macro individually for worksheets that have a corresponding worksheet in Workbook B instead of having VBA loop for the worksheets in another workbook. Even If one of the worksheets don't have a match, the Subscript out of range shows up. Is there any error suppressing function that can check for  'SubScript out of range responses' ?

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelt `WorksheetFunction`.

Also, the workbook "2012SWD.xlsx" needs to be already be open (the Workbooks collection only refers to open workbooks), and check that its extension is not .xlsm (or some other).

..and, what Tim said :)

Comment: Thanks, they was a villian too (the misspelling)... In addition to Time's comments